# c xml lib how to search my node

Tags: c, xml

heelo, for read my xml file i use in c this small library :
https://github.com/ooxi/xml.c

But i have a problem, i want to search a value by node name like this code :

```
    #include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "./xml.h"


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    /* XML source, could be read from disk
     */
    uint8_t* source = ""
        "<Root>"
            "<Hello>World</Hello>"


            "<Functions>"

            "<Function>"
            "<as>testas</as>"
            "<os>testos</os>"
            "</Function>"

            "<Function>"
            "<is>testis</is>"
            "<us>testus</us>"
            "<ls>testls</ls>"
            "</Function>"

            "<Function>"
            "<mn>testmn</mn>"
            "</Function>"

            "</Functions>"

        "</Root>"
    ;

    struct xml_document* document = xml_parse_document(source, strlen(source));

    if (!document) {
        printf("Could parse document\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    struct xml_node* root = xml_document_root(document);

    struct xml_node* root_hello = xml_node_child(root, 0);
    struct xml_string* hello = xml_node_name(root_hello);
    struct xml_string* world = xml_node_content(root_hello);

    uint8_t* hello_0 = calloc(xml_string_length(hello) + 1, sizeof(uint8_t));
    uint8_t* world_0 = calloc(xml_string_length(world) + 1, sizeof(uint8_t));
    xml_string_copy(hello, hello_0, xml_string_length(hello));
    xml_string_copy(world, world_0, xml_string_length(world));



    printf("%s %s\n", hello_0, world_0);
    free(hello_0);
    free(world_0);


    struct xml_node* root_this = xml_easy_child(root, "Functions",0);


    unsigned long number_of_function=(unsigned long)xml_node_children(root_this);
    printf("Root/This has %lu children\n", number_of_function);

    int i=0;

    // i want to search value of node "us" for example
    for (i=0;i<number_of_function;i++) {
        printf("%i \n ",i);

        struct xml_node* TMP_function_node = xml_easy_child(root, "Functions", 0, i);
        struct xml_string* TMP_function = xml_node_content(TMP_function_node);
        uint8_t* TMP_function_0 = calloc(xml_string_length(TMP_function) + 1, sizeof(uint8_t));
        xml_string_copy(TMP_function, TMP_function_0, xml_string_length(TMP_function));
        printf("%s\n", TMP_function_0);
    }

    xml_document_free(document, false);
}
```

in this code, i want to get value of my node "us" for example, in root/Functions/function/us
but how can i make this, because i have many "Function" node.

thanks for advance for your help

Comment: Have you gone through this https://github.com/ooxi/xml.c/blob/master/src/xml.c , 
struct xml_document* xml_parse_document(uint8_t* buffer, size_t length)/ static struct xml_node* xml_parse_node(struct xml_parser* parser)

Comment: it's private function, i can not use this

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through this [github.com/ooxi/xml.c/blob/master/src/xml.c](http://github.com/ooxi/xml.c/blob/master/src/xml.c)

```
struct xml_document* xml_parse_document(uint8_t* buffer, size_t length)



static struct xml_node* xml_parse_node(struct xml_parser* parser)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but when i use this :
struct xml_node* bob= xml_parse_node(document);

i have this error : undefined reference to `xml_parse_node'

it's private function, i can not use this

Comment: It’s the function inside xml.c which you told you are using. If you are looking for other xml parser in c then you can try libxml